# codeigniter view parameter "caching"

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching, view

i've been working with CI for almost a year now and i could almost solve any problem i had.

but now i've run in to a wall with something that looks like parameter caching for views.

EXAMPLE

Controller method:

```
public function cache_test()
{
    $data['dummy'] = "foobar"; 
    $this->load->view('cache_view', $data); // should output "foobar"

    unset($data['dummy']);
    $this->load->view('cache_view', $data); // should output nothing
}
```

view:

```
<? if(isset($dummy)): ?>
    <?= $dummy ?>
<? endif; ?>
```

result:

```
foobar  foobar
```

i found a workaround where you have to set the variable to an empty string

```
$data['dummy'] = ""
```

and then make change the if to

```
if(isset($dummy) && $dummy != "")
```

but this doesnt seem very clean to me, and stuff like this bugs me :/

any help or pointers in the right direction are highly appreciated.

EDIT: 
i want to use this to load several items of a menu, where some of the view parameters are optional. these optional parameters then decide if i show some content in the view or not.

Answer (score -1):

You can try following code , may be it will be solved your problem

```
public function cache_test()
{
    $data['dummy'] = "foobar"; 
    $this->load->view('cache_view', $data); // should output "foobar"

    unset($data);
    $this->load->view('cache_view', $data); // should output nothing
}
```

Comment: your proposition produces an error on the 2nd view load since $data is undefined there. also i dont want to unset ALL the parameters.